# Unable to run any systemd services in WSL

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubernetes

None of the systemd commands are working inside WSL( Ubuntu Bash 18.04).
When I ran `sudo systemctl is-active kubelet`, error is
`output: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
: running command: sudo systemctl is-active kubelet`

How to enable systemd feature in WSL? Whats the way to get rid of `System has not been booted with systemd`

Comment: Eh you assume systemd works in WSL. I really doubt that.

Comment: Crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55579342/5830574

Answer (score 5):

`cron` is a `systemd` service which you can still run in WSL. See this answer as a guide for how you might setup your `kubelet` application:

- [How can I run services in WSL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025478/307523)

To expand on this link, you can modify Windows startup to load WSL with the background services minimized:

- [WSL Tips: Starting Linux Background Services on Windows Login](https://dev.to/ironfroggy/wsl-tips-starting-linux-background-services-on-windows-login-3o98)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you can try:

`sudo service docker start`

when using WSL2, if you are running on windows version 2004 or higher (I assume).

Answer (score 1):

To run systemd inside WSL2, clone the following repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.git
```

Run the cloned script:

```
cd ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script
bash ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.sh
```

Restart Ubuntu shell then try running the command `systemctl` to make sure systemd is working.

Comment: This is the same as earlier answer but has content and no link. Since this depends on a script in Github to work, if the link breaks **both this and the other answer** will no longer be useful. Also, this repo is from 2 years ago and not supported.

Answer (score -1):

There is a cool workaround to enable systemd in WSL. Worked for me. Please refer [here](https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script)

Also, for Docker, make sure you have the latest version of it installed and WSL2 is running at least on Windows version 2004. Also make sure to enable WSL2 support in Docker settings.

Comment: Link only answers are considered low quality and they become obsolete if the link is changed, moved, or deleted.  You should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1283733/edit) your answer and make sure that the essential parts of your solution are in your answer here.  Nobody should actually have to visit any link to understand your solution.  https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: This is the same as later answer with no link. Since this depends on a script in Github to work, if the link breaks **both this and the other answer** will no longer be useful. Also, this repo is from 2 years ago and not supported.